# about subnetting ip adress 172.16.0.0

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip-address

can you explain why we have 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.0.0 so it can't be for example 172.13.0.0 to 172.35.0.0.
And also why is 192.168.0.0 and is it possible to be 192.160.0.0? thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should also check out https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.

Comment: "_about subnetting ip adress 172.16.0.0_" You do not subnet addresses; you subnet networks. The Private IPv4 network is `172.16.0.0/12`, as defined in RFC 1918. You can subnet that network into any longer-prefix, private network(s) you want.